# ASP.NET Identity ¿Cómo acceder al perfil de usuario desde javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables, identity

Tengo una vista (ASP.NET MVC 5) en la que muestro unos datos utilizando el plugin DataTables de jQuery.
El html es este:

```
 <table id="tabla" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>CIF</th>
          <th>FechaAlta</th>
          <th>FechaBaja</th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
  </table>
```

A la tabla le añado dos columnas de botón, una para Ver el detalle de la empresa y otro para Editar sus datos.
Lo hago así:

```
 columnDefs: [
        { targets: [0], visible: false, searchable: false },  //Clave primaria
        { targets: [1], visible: true, searchable: true, orderable: true },  //Empresa
        { targets: [2], visible: true, searchable: true, orderable: true },  //NIF
        { targets: [3], visible: true, searchable: false, orderable: true },  //Fecha alta
        { targets: [4], visible: true, searchable: false, orderable: false },  //Fecha baja
        { targets: [5], visible: true, searchable: false, orderable: false },  //Botón Ver
        { targets: [6], visible: true, searchable: false, orderable: false }  //Botón Editar
     ],
     columns: [
        { data: "Id", name: "Id" },
        { data: "Nombre", name: "Nombre", title: "Empresa" },
        { data: "CIF", name: "CIF", title: "CIF" },
        { data: "FechaAlta", name: "FechaAlta", title: "Fecha de alta" },
        { data: "FechaBaja", name: "FechaBaja", title: "Fecha de baja" },
        {
           "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
              return '<a href="' + window._verUrl.replace('{Id}', full.Id) + '"  title="Ver"><i class="ion ion-md-eye"></i></a>';
           }
        },
        {
           "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
              return '<a href="' + window._editarUrl.replace('{Id}', full.Id) + '" title="Modificar"><i class="ion ion-md-create"></i></a>';
           }
        }
     ],
```

Lo que necesito es que la columna con el botón de Editar, esté disponible solamente para determinados perfiles o roles de usuario.
He estado buscando durante horas y no he encontrado un ejemplo o pista de como acceder a la información de Identity desde javascript, si es que puede hacerse.
En cualquier caso necesito que esa columna solo sea accesible para unos perfiles de usuario concretos.

Comment: Directamente creo que no puedes, nosotros guardamos esos datos en campos ocultos o variables de sesion. De todas formas puedes pintar esa tabla con algún gridview y así es todo accesible 100% desde servidor.

Comment: Porque no usas el sistema de roles de identity compruebas si el usuario es parte del rol permitido, si es así regresas todo de lo contrario solo regresas la parte permitida tal vez devolviendo null el dato que agregas a tu etiqueta `a` que usas como botón editar

Comment: Denifer, eso es lo que me gustaría hacer, pero no se como llevar la información de Identity al javascript. GDP, Lo de utilizar campos ocultos no me parece muy seguro y las tablas las he de representar así por temas de estilo.